# How to join two tables based on date? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates, left-join, intervals, dateadd

I'm trying to join two tables that have check date in both. The results should show only if the check date in the first table is equal to the check date in the second table. OR if the check date in both tables is within 10 days of each other.

I have two tables:

```
t1 table: company_id, expected_checkdate

t2 table: company_id, actual_checkdate
```

- **Condition 1:** acutal_checkdate = expected_checkdate
- **Condition 2:** acutal_checkdate within 10 days of expected_checkdate
- **Condition 3:** expected_checkdate within 10 days of acutal_checkdate
- **Condtion 4:** if acutal_checkdate = expected_checkdate then don't check for others that are within 10 days

  ```
    LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.actual_checkdate = t2.expected_checkdate
         OR t1.actual_checkdate 
         BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t2.expected_checkdate, INTERVAL -10 DAY) 
           AND DATE_ADD(t2.expected_checkdate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
         AND t1.company_id = t2.company_id
  ```

The problem is when I run this for one month. I'm seeing a lot of duplicates because there can be 2 actual_checkdate entries or 2 expected_checkdate in one month.

```
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |     company_id      | actual_checkdate |expected_checkdate|
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |          12         |    2018-01-05    |    2018-01-05    |
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |          12         |    2018-01-19    |    2018-01-19    |
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |          12         |    2018-01-05    |    2018-01-19    | -- incorrect 
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |          12         |    2018-01-19    |    2018-01-05    | -- incorrect 
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |          13         |    2018-01-12    |    2018-01-20    | 
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
      |          14         |    2018-01-26    |    2018-01-36    | 
      |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

The first two and last two rows are correct. The third and fourth rows shouldn't display because they are duplicates of the first and second row. Please help me with the join above.

Comment: Hi. You are neither describing nor coding for the actual table you want. Give the condition under which a row is in the result, in terms of its columns. "join the tables to find if ..." is not clear or precise. Note also that it happens to be phrased in a style that parahrases code, which *can* be ok, but which is not the style of phrasing I just suggested. PS Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy I edited the posting. Is this correct?

Comment: Given an interval of +/- 10 days there's no way your two incorrect lines can appear in the output as they don't meet the `BETWEEN` condition

Comment: Your condition is parsed as `(t1.a = t2.e) OR ((t1.a BETWEEN ... AND ...) AND t1.id = t2.id)` but you want `((t1.a = t2.e) OR (t1.a BETWEEN ... AND ...)) AND t1.id = t2.id`. Your conditions are meant to be applied to *rows in `t1 join t2 using id`*. Ie if you had done what I said & described *exactly when a row goes in the result* then you would get, rows where "company t1.id has expected t1.e & company t2.id has actual t2.a & t1.id=t2.id & conditions". That's `t1 join t2 on id & (OR of 4 conditions)`. PS But have you actually described the rows you really want? (I suspect not.) PPS [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your `JOIN` condition as:

```
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.company_id = t2.company_id AND
   (t1.actual_checkdate = t2.expected_checkdate OR
    t1.actual_checkdate BETWEEN 
       DATE_SUB(t2.expected_checkdate, INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
       AND DATE_ADD(t2.expected_checkdate, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.actual_checkdate = t2.expected_checkdate AND t1.company_id = t2.company_id)
 )
```

The NOT EXISTS clause will prevent matching on a nearby date if an actual match exists.

Comment: Does the Interval include t1.actual_checkdate = t2.expected_checkdate?

Comment: Yes that is why I have the NOT EXISTS clause to prevent the interval matching when there is already an exact match. Because of the NOT EXISTS clause you can't use the interval to also check for the exact match, that is why the check for the exact match is also in the WHERE clause.